# Shebang in JavaScript ignored when executed as command in Docker with "/bin/bash" as entrypoint

Tags: docker, dockerfile, shebang

When I try to execute a JavaScript file with a shebang such as `#!/usr/bin/env node` through the command argument of `docker run ...` it seems to "ignore" the shebang.

```
$ docker run --rm foobar/hello-world /hello-world.js
/hello-world.js: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `'Hello, World!''
/hello-world.js: line 2: `console.log('Hello, World!');'
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:13.12-alpine
COPY hello-world.js /hello-world.js
RUN chmod +x /hello-world.js
RUN apk update && apk update && apk add bash
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash"]
```

**hello-world.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
console.log('Hello, World!');
```

When I use `/hello-world.js` as the entrypoint directly (`ENTRYPOINT ["/hello-world.js"]`) it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `-c` to the entrypoint so bash will expect a command. Without `-c` it interprets its argument as the name of a bash script to execute.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
```

Comment: I know that asking this questions saved me a couple of hours right now, but at the same time, I should've noticed the "-c" that I saw people adding to it in other questions and issues... John, you're a life saver!

Comment: Note that this will cause all arguments to the command to be ignored, unless the "command" is a single-word quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just setting the default `CMD` to the program you're installing in your container, and generally preferring `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT` if you only need one of them.

```sh
FROM node:13.12-alpine
COPY hello-world.js /hello-world.js
RUN chmod +x /hello-world.js
CMD ["/hello-world.js"]
```

When you provide a command at the `docker run` command line, it overrides the Dockerfile `CMD` (if any), and it's appended to the `ENTRYPOINT`.  In your original example the `ENTRYPOINT` from the Dockerfile is combined with the `docker run` command and you're getting a combined command `bash /hello-world.js`.

If you do need an interactive shell to debug the container, you can launch that with

```sh
docker run --rm -it foobar/hello-world /bin/sh
```